# How to configure settings file to recognize translation.py, when using django-modeltranslation

Tags: django, multilingual

I have begun testing django-modeltranslation and cannot seem to get my translation.py file recognized.  Getting a "no translation.py found in the project directory" msg when running the sqlall command.

I have the following:

- modeltranslation residing in /Users/judy/project
- a project called andor in /Users/judy/project
- a translation.py in /Users/judy/project/andor
- a settings file for andor that includes the following pertinent items:

  - modeltranslation included in INSTALLED_APPS list
  - required languages included in the LANGUAGES list
  - TRANSLATION_REGISTRY = 'andor.translation'
  - PYTHONPATH that includes /Users/judy/project/andor

Thought this was it per directions included at this site:  http://code.google.com/p/django-modeltranslation/wiki/InstallationAndUsage

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade to latest svn, the setting TRANSLATION_REGISTRY has been removed recently. Just keep translation.py in your project folder.